# I am getting "failed to open APK: I/O error." when running a xamarin forms app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am just learning Xamarin forms and I just changed the MainPage.xaml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TravelRecordApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Entry Placeholder="Email Address" Keyboard="Email"/>
        <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" />
        <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Text="Log in" Clicked="LoginButton_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

When I run the app using android emulator I got the error error APT2096: failed to open APK: I/O error.
I am also getting this in console output Unable to open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar': No such file or directory

Comment: First of all, please open the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms` path, If it existed, If not, please open your VS. click the Android SDKs and Tools, If enable the settings like this screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/2YCbxJO

Comment: Are there any update for this issue?

Comment: ok that worked, thanks

Comment: Ok, please share you solution to answer and mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Actually you should have added it in answers

Comment: I added it to answer. please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please open the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms path` If it existed.

If not, please open your VS. Click the `Android SDKs and Tools`, if enable the settings like this screenshot.

[image]